# Is anonymity not allowed on this site.

Tags: discussion

I have noticed that on [this](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/4340/is-asking-about-u-s-citizenship-an-illegal-interview-question) question, I have been met with a lot of hostility. For example,

> @picakhu, you need to see the complete I-9 handbook. If you do, you'll find that you're mixing two different categories. Permanent residency cards have expiration dates...as do driver's licenses and passports. It doesn't mean the card or license or passport is revoked after X years; it means you have to renew. The I-9 booklet is cautioning against rejecting a worker's authorization documents merely because they have an expiration date. – Kyralessa

and

> @picakhu " I do not wish to disclose my status. " in that case, expect hiring managers to think you're an illegal or at least trying to get a job without the required status or work permits. And as hiring something like that is a crime with severe penalties, they shouldn't hire you. – jwenting

Which I feel suggest that

> 1. I am unable to reason reasonably well or understand my situation
> 2. I should be disallowed from keeping any personal information to myself

I think such hostility should be challenged by the moderators and some rectification is necessary.

If I am wrong on either of those counts, I would like to know.

Answer (score 6):

The first quote draws your attention to I-9 and what it says about employment.

The second quote speculates what hiring managers might think of your not disclosing your "status".

Neither seems to be relevant to your anonymousness, especially "to your anonymousness on this site".

Speaking for myself, I've noticed that you're not using an Anglo-saxon name or nickname, noticed that you're using a name spelled with a Latinish alphabet, noticed that your name (or self-chosen nickname, I don't know) is similar to a Pokemon character's (forgive me: that's the closest I've come) and that it's spelled with initial lower-case letter, and I haven't take the time to view whatever [your profile information](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/users/1229/picakhu) is, and I note that I consider myself to be a politically correct Canadian [many/most of whose colleagues are born abroad](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/4370), and that other countries/people might not share my views about political correctness.

Anyway I don't see any "hostility" in the fragments you quoted, I'm sorry you feel hostility, and of course (IMO) anonymousness (to whatever extent anonymousness is possible on the Internet) is "allowed" on this site.

Comment: By "anonymousness" I mean my right to keep between myself and my potential employers my legal employability status and not to reveal it to every Tom, Dick and Harry on the Internet. In addition, +1 for figuring out that my name is a distorted pokemon name. I value my privacy especially on a website like this, perhaps my fear is irrational, but it exists none the less.

Comment: Also, about the first quote, assuming you know why it was written. You will realize that the author specifically claims that I do not know what I am talking about, which I find, at the very least, assumptive.

Comment: @picakhu This meta-topic implies that you're extrapolating from "stateless in front of an employer" to "anonymous in this internet forum"; and, extrapolating from "opinion of Kyralessa" (who by the way I've known for ages, or at least seen on StackExchange for ages, and haven't noted as a bad person and don't remember ever being unreasonable) to "opinion of everyone on the forum". I understand that this is a personal/sensitve/delicate/important subject for you. I don't think Kyralessa means to be offensive nor require you to decloak on this forum: only telling you to read and understand I-9.

Comment: thank you for understanding the point behind this meta question.

Answer (score 3):

I don't see those comments as hostile, they seem to just try to explain the US immigration law. The point about disclosing your status seems to be about applying to a job, it is not a comment about this site. If anything is hostile here, it's probably the law, I don't see any hostility by users there.

In general, if you find certain comments offensive, just flag them.

Comment: on this site, I am looking to see if the way I am being treated(by companies) is allowed(legal) by law. The comments are either presumptive about my understanding of the law or made in bad faith. In either case, if I have misunderstood the concern of the two individuals, I would like to apologize to them.

Comment: @picakhu - If/when you ask a question about law I think you ought to have a little extra forgiveness for any answer/answerer which implies that you don't currently understand the law, and tells you where to read more about it.